# Map JSON file to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, web-crawler

Im parsing one website and want to write to MySQL. There is 11 field needs to parse each url under specific field.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib.request
    import csv
    import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'root',passwd = 'root',db = 'micro')

with open(r"C:\Users\New folder\url_list.txt") as f:

urls = [u.strip('\n') for u in f.readlines()]
page = 0

while page < 1000:
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urls[page]).content, "html.parser")
        text = soup.select("head script[type=text/javascript]")[-1].text
        start = text.find('dataLayer =') + len('dataLayer =')
        end = text.rfind(';')
        rows = text[start:end].strip().split('\n')
    except:
        pass
    for d in rows:
        print(d)
    page = page + 1
    print(page)
```

Here is my JSON file

```
[{
     'page':'ProductPage',
      'OAM':'False',
      'storeNum':'029',
      'brand':'ASUS',
      'productPrice':'199.99',
     'SKU':'576181',
     'productID':'443759',
     'mpn':'RT-AC3200',
     'ean':'886227780914',
      'category':'Wireless Routers',
     'isMobile':'False'
}]
[{
     'page':'ProductPage',
      'OAM':'False',
      'storeNum':'029',
      'brand':'Linksys',
      'productPrice':'79.99',
     'SKU':'244129',
     'productID':'432549',
     'mpn':'EA6350',
     'ean':'745883644780',
      'category':'Wireless Routers',
     'isMobile':'False'
}]
```

How can i map this JSON into MYSQL. Here is the output what i need. [Here is what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150fe.jpg) Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. That is not JSON. 2. You import `json` but don't use it. 3. You create `urls2` but only use `urls`. 4. What is the connection between the JSON file and your code? 5. It sounds like you want to do a simple SQL insert. Have you actually tried? We're not here to write code for you. 6. A bare `except: pass` is a terrible idea, at least print the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one crude way that you can populate a SQL insert statement with the data you have.

```
rows=[
[{
     'page':'ProductPage',
      'OAM':'False',
      'storeNum':'029',
      'brand':'ASUS',
      'productPrice':'199.99',
     'SKU':'576181',
     'productID':'443759',
     'mpn':'RT-AC3200',
     'ean':'886227780914',
      'category':'Wireless Routers',
     'isMobile':'False'
}],
[{
     'page':'ProductPage',
      'OAM':'False',
      'storeNum':'029',
      'brand':'Linksys',
      'productPrice':'79.99',
     'SKU':'244129',
     'productID':'432549',
     'mpn':'EA6350',
     'ean':'745883644780',
      'category':'Wireless Routers',
     'isMobile':'False'
}]
]


for d in rows:
    sql = "insert into tableName \n( "
    recordInfo=d[0]
    sql += ' '. join ([field for field in recordInfo] )
    sql += ') \nvalues ( '
    sql += ('***, '*len(recordInfo))[:-2]
    sql += ') **** \n('
    sql += ', '.join (["'%s'" % recordInfo[field] for field in recordInfo])
    sql += ')'
    print (sql)
    #~ con.execute(sql.replace('****', '%').replace('***',"'%s'"))
```